# Create a boost asio ssl context from SSL_CTX

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl, boost-asio

Is it possible to create an `boost::asio::ssl::context` from an existing `SSL_CTX`?

I would like to avoid copying all the options from one to the other (thus risking a bug).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two constructors [I see are](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__context/context.html)

```
/// Constructor.
BOOST_ASIO_DECL explicit context(method m);

/// Construct to take ownership of a native handle.
BOOST_ASIO_DECL explicit context(native_handle_type native_handle);
```

So the second would logically be the one you're after:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ecc82782a6edcf4)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
int main() {
    const SSL_METHOD* raw_method = SSLv23_server_method();
    SSL_CTX*          raw_ctx    = SSL_CTX_new(raw_method);

    boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(raw_ctx);
} // Note: no SSL_CTX_free(raw_ctx)!
```

Be careful: if you use this constructor, it does take ownership. This means that you MUST NOT attempt to free the context (or any substituent part, (default) password app user data), because that will cause double-free. There is no way to release ownership from an `asio::ssl::context` instance.

Comment: Can I use the same `raw_ctx` from one call to the other ? It looks like it should not be possible but it seems to work ...

Comment: @Dorian why not? The context is specifically designed to be shared, and as long as you don't throw it away.... You should show your code for a more concrete review

Comment: You are right I will try to come up with a minimalist example with more context. I'm actually trying to use `libwebsocketpp` and wondering what I should write in the `on_tls_init` handler.